# Node / Express Directory Browsing

Tags: arrays, node.js, object, recursion, express

Im trying all day long to solve this problem:

I have an directory with subdirectories, f.e.:

```
 | Music Artist 1
 | - Album Nr 1
 | -- Track 1
 | -- Track 2
 | -- ...
 | - Album Nr 2
 | -- Track 1
 | -- Track 2
 | -- ...
 | Music Artist 2
 | - Album Nr 1
 | -- Track 1
 | -- Track 2
 | -- ...
```

Now, i will loop through these directories - with adding all the details to an array / object.
So it should look like this:

```
 [ { artist: Music Artist 1, album { title: Album Nr1, songs: { title: Track 1 } ... } ]
```

Getting all dir names / files is not the problem. I just don't get how to create the arrays :(

Thanks in advanced!

Edit:
This is my try: http://pastebin.com/vWnbvu5m

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but what's wrong with .push()?

Comment: Hm, it could be that easy ... but I'm a total JS / node nub.

If i do an
    var array = []
before my directory loop I don't know how to handle the key / value by using .push()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `artist` objects and `push()` each one you create into an array. Similarly, `album` and `song` may be objects `push()`ed into corresponding arrays attached to their parent objects.

```
var artists = [];
// for each artist we have
    var artist = {};
    artist.name = 'Music Artist 1';
    artist.albums = [];
    // for each album we have
        var album = {};
        album.title = 'Album Nr1'
        album.songs = [];
        // for each song that we have
            var song = {};
            song.title = 'Track 1';
            album.songs.push(song);
        // end song loop
        artist.albums.push(album);
    // end album loop
    artists.push(artist)
// end artist loop
```

If you then need this information in JSON format, you can parse it using a JSON parser. Or you can programmatically read data from each `artist` by looping over the `artists` array.

```
// returns name of first artist in array
artists[0].name;

// returns title of first album by first artist in respective arrays
artists[0].albums[0].title;

// returns title of first song in first album by first artist in respective arrays
artists[0].albums[0].songs[0].title;
```

Comment: Since you have `recursion` tagged, I assume you are recursing over the directories. If you need help applying this recursively, please add your code to the question and let me know. Cheers!